# WordPress Category Permalink Setup Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have a new WordPress site that is migrating from an old Non-WordPress site. So the URL structure was different. I'm struggling to get it similar as it was before.

The OLD URL structure

```
https://test.com/[dynamic-category]/listing-name
IE: test.com/automotive/aaa-auto-company
```

And, the domain.com/automotive, was the archive page for all listings automotive.
Using the WordPress permalinks *does not* work with the ***"/%category%/%postname%/"***

This is a custom post type/taxonomies and Has Archive enabled.

The current URL structure is

```
https://test.com/listing-category/automotive <<-- Archive
https://test.com/listing/aaa-auto-company <<-- Listing
```

So in short, how do I get my custom post type to match the OLD URL structure

```
https://test.com/automotive/aaa-auto-company
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `rewrite` option to the options array when registering post types and custom taxonomies.

Example:

```
https://test.com/listing-category/automotive <<-- Archive
https://test.com/listing/aaa-auto-company <<-- Listing
```

```php
// .... registering listing post type
'rewrite'         => array(
    'slug' => 'listings'
);
```

Resulting in this:

```
https://test.com/listings/aaa-auto-company <<-- Listing
```

Then again in your taxonomy register options

```php
// .... registering listing-category taxonomy
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'listing'
);
```

```
https://test.com/listing/automotive <<-- Archive
```

As far as getting them to be exatly the same? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Yeah that's closer, but, instead of listing, it needs to be the dynamic category. IE: /automotive/automotive-company/

Comment: Rewriting just does the first section, the term would do the 2nd bit, so for example Automotive is the taxonomy name and Nissan is a term (category) of that taxonomy with some car posts inside

Comment: You also need to flush rewrite rules when rewriting... go to permalink settings and just press save.

Comment: Yeah, but you still will have /listing/automotive/automotive-company
.... would like just, /automotive/automotive-company